# Серверу по-барабану как к нему обращаются

Tags: linux, nginx

В nginx в sites-enable лежат разные конфигурации, которые обрабатывают запросы с разными server_name (в одном - sub1.addr.com второй - sub2.addr.com).. В nginx.conf точно инклюдятся все конфиги! Когда обращаюсь к серверу как к sub1.addr.com или sub2.addr.com или просто addr.com (этот вообще не обрабатываю!) он мне показывает страницу для sub1.addr.com (объясняю это тем, что она первая из соображения алфавитного порядка импортирутся в конфиг)...

Как мне сделать так чтобы сервер все-таки разделял эти имена? Может у меня где-то редирект прописан, а я не знаю?

Comment: Конфиг и запросы в студию

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Nginx перезагружали? Он подхватывает конфиг только после перезагрузки `sudo service nginx reload`, например. Далее - ищите ошибку по `nginx -T` - он выводит весь конфиг, как его видит Nginx.